# How to add Parameter with each route

Tags: reactjs

I am working on one `ReactJs` application.Here i need to add a `parameter` with each route.
My current implementation.

```
<Route path=":/username" element={<Home />} />

<Route path=":/username/profile" element={<Profile />} />

`<Route path=":/username/about" element={<About />} />
```

Here want i to once user enters username i want to add this with each and every route.
Here if i need to navigate from one page to other i need to get username from local storage

`const name=localStorage('username")`;

```
history.push(/+name+/"profile")
```

These two steps i need to do every where i need to push user.
Is there any way to automatically add username without accessing in each and every page.Or any better way

Answer (score 1):

This way you can use nested route in react router v6. In this way you need to write the root path only once. Read more about this from [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/route)

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/:username" element={<Home />}>
        <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<Route path="/:username/profile" element={<Profile />} />
```

Then in the Profile component, do this to access the username parameter:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { username } = useParams();
```

Now you can use the username from the url parameter in Profile instead of using local storage. Here's [a good article on React Router URL parameters](https://ui.dev/react-router-url-parameters).